# Application security scanner

Tags: security, findbugs, brakeman, sast

I am working on a project to develop a SAST(static application security testing) scanner. Can people suggest best practices to read the code base quicker?

I got few ideas like using AST or BCEL.

Please suggest

Comment: Probably not worth a full answer, but if you haven't already, I'd recommend looking into semgrep https://semgrep.dev/

Comment: Thanks , let me look into

Comment: That sounds like a huge project! I guess your first step will be to decide how you want your code scanning engine to work: will you build a simple regex-based engine? Will you build a full code parser that parses code into language trees and symbol tables (ie half way to a compiler)? Will you build a data flow analyzer? Each has their pros and cons as they are better or worse at detecting different kinds of security issues.